# Prevent responsive menu from auto-collapsing in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, menu, autoscroll

My responsive menu is auto-collapsing to "display none" when I click the menu button, in both directions: when I click to hide or when I click to show it.
I tried modifying styles, and main js but had no result. I realy can't figureoute what could be the problem.

I am using Bootstrap as framework and have an autoscroller animation, maybe there is the problem.

I let the link here: https://davidpulido.com.mx/

I'll be glad if you can helpme.

Comment: Please post the HTML and JavaScript (if any) code. I only see you have styles `.collapse:not(.show) { display:none; }` in `_transitions.scss` that caused the issue, but have no idea what is calling it.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I tried to find where it is trigged too, but didn't find it in any part, thats why I didn't post any specific code :S